# Paypal rest API gives Internal Error

Tags: web-services, paypal, paypal-sandbox, netsuite

I have been working on payment api,credit card payment method I am getting error code 500 .I tried with different payment type also but i keep getting this error.any workaround or solutions??? I tried this with sandbox and production too

request Header:

```
   var header = {
                    'Authorization': authstr,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };
```

request body:

```
{"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4341848462238769","type":"visa","expire_month":5,"expire_year":2021,"cvv":"982","first_name":"Delwin","last_name":"thomas","billing_address":{"line1":"111 First Street","city":"Saratoga","state":"CA","postal_code":"95070","country_code":"US"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"18.46","currency":"USD"},"description":"Check Transaction"}]}
```

Response:

```
{"type":"http.ClientResponse","code":500,"headers":{"paypal-debug-id":"a656f7398753","Paypal-Debug-Id":"a656f7398753","Server":"Apache","Connection":"close","HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR":"sandbox.slc","Set-Cookie":"X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dapiplatformproxyserv%26TIME%3D1779291994%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Wed, 18 Apr 2018 09:48:34 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly","Vary":"Authorization","Content-Length":"0","Date":"Wed, 18 Apr 2018 09:18:34 GMT","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1","Via":"1.1 mono003.prod.dub.netledger.com"},"body":""}
```

Comment: I really hope those are not real CC details you've posted there...

Comment: yea, those are not real card info. Nothing to worry. It seems like a onetime issue and now you are able to process the payments. Can you please try and post the debug id if you are still seeing this issue.

Comment: I keep getting this error "type":"http.ClientResponse","code":500,"headers":{"paypal-debug-id":"677be450dbf8a","Paypal-Debug-Id":"677be450dbf8a"